# Get highest number for unique object in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to find the highest number `tv` for each unique `version_title`.
I have stored all necessary values in a dict and want to keep it as fast and efficient as possible.

```
# Store all timelines existing with it's information in a dict
for tl_index in range(1, timelines_total+1):
    timeline_data[project.GetTlbyI(tl_index).GetDependingName()] = {
        "name": project.GetTlbyI(tl_index).GetDependingName(),
        "version_title": project.GetTlbyI(tl_index).GetDependingName().split('_')[3],
        "stage": project.GetTlbyI(tl_index).GetDependingName().split('_')[4] + "_" + project.GetTlbyI(tl_index).GetDependingName().split('_')[5],
        "tv": int(project.GetTlbyI(tl_index).GetDependingName().split('_')[6][2:4])
        }

pprint(timeline_data)


# Find all existing Version-Titles
version_titles = []
for name, timeline_info in timeline_data.items():
    version_titles.append(timeline_info['version_title'])
    # print(timeline_info['version_title'], timeline_info['tv'])  # Print Edit-Version-Title and Version Number


# Generate list of unique Version-Titles
unique_version_titles = (list(set(version_titles)))
print(unique_version_titles)


for name, timeline_info in timeline_data.items():
    print(timeline_info['version_title'], timeline_info['tv'])
```

### `pprint(timeline_data)` result is:

```
{'1912_Sample_File_ALLin_03_Anim_Tv02_PV01_200421': {'stage': '03_Anim',
                                                                    'version_title': 'ALLin',
                                                                    'name': '1912_Sample_File_ALLin_03_Anim_Tv02_PV01_200421',
                                                                    'tv': 2},
 '1912_Sample_File_ALLin_05_Load_Tv01_PV01_200421': {'stage': '05_Load',
                                                                    'version_title': 'ALLin',
                                                                    'name': '1912_Sample_File_ALLin_05_Load_Tv01_PV01_200421',
                                                                    'tv': 1},
 '1912_Sample_File_TVC60sec_07_Rough_Tv03_PV01_200421': {'stage': '07_Rough',
                                                                       'version_title': 'TVC60sec',
                                                                       'name': '1912_Sample_File_TVC60sec_07_Rough_Tv03_PV01_200421',
                                                                       'tv': 3}}
```

### `unique_version_titles` content is:

```
['TVC60sec', 'ALLin']
```

### The result I'm looking for:

```
# A dict with the highest value for each unique `version_title`.

{highest_value: {'ALL_in': 2, "TVC60sec": 3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultdict` might be very helpful in this case. Try:

```
from collections import defaultdict
highest = defaultdict(int)
for t in timeline_data.values():
    title, tv = t["version_title"], t["tv"]
    if highest[title] < tv:
        highest[title] = tv
output = {"highest_value": dict(highest)}
print(output) # output: {'highest_value': {'ALLin': 2, 'TVC60sec': 3}}
```

Comment: This is insane. It works like charm!!! So thankful for that answer. But I don't understand what `defaultdict` is doing for now?

Comment: @BenjaminK Happy to help :) While "regular" dict returns `KeyError` if you access a key that doesn't exist, `defaultdict(<type>)` wouldn't not raise an error but will return the default type you defined. So if you define `defaultdict(int)`, it will return 0 if the key doesn't exist. If you define `defaultdict(list)`, it will return empty list, etc. Does is make sense for you?

Comment: Might I ask another question. How can you compare a str with an int? In line `if highest[title] < tv:`

Comment: @BenjaminK The comparison is between 2 numerics. `highest` is a dictionary with string keys (title) and numeric values (tv) so `highest[title]` is the `tv` value of specific key (the value behind the variable title). Thanks to the defaultdict, if the key doesn't exists `highest[title]` equals to 0 so it will be numeric in all cases.

Comment: How can I access the default dict. It always gives me an error I guess this comes from `<type 'int'>`  `defaultdict(<type 'int'>, 'TVC60sec': 3, 'ALLin': 2, 'TVC15sec': 1})` This for example doesn't work `print(highest['defaultdict']['ALLin'])`

Comment: @BenjaminK how are you trying to access it?

Comment: Just do: `highest['ALLin']`

Comment: This fixed the last open question to `defaultdict`. Thank you for that in-depth answer!